# Calling external bash command in Python (os.subprocess) with Linux subsystem

Tags: python, linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows 10 system and Ubuntu subsystem installed on my computer.
I would like to execute a bash command in my Python scipt with os.subprocess but how could I do it if my Unix subsystem is "only" set as subsystem?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running the Python script within WSL or on the Windows side? If you are running it within WSL, it should be as simple as just using `os.subprocess`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'wsl' in front of the command. For example

```
subprocess.run("wsl pwd", shell=True)
```